# LINQ: Searching a collection within a collection for a single object

Tags: c#, linq

I am looking for a nice simple LINQ query that can get an item that is in a collection of a collection. Consider the following models...

```
class Customer
{
   List<Order> Orders;
   int ID;
}

class Order
{
   int ID;
}
```

Lets say I have a list of type customer...

```
List<Customer> Customers;
```

What I want is a ***single Order*** based on the ID of the Order (this is my known input data). I also can assume that an Order is unique to a customer (so there will only be one Order with the ID I am looking for across all customers)

***Is there a nice LINQ query I can use to get the Order I am looking for?***

I know I can easily do this over a single list of Orders, but this is the set up I have to work with. I do not want to be querying for more data, ff I already have enough in memory to get what I need.

I could do this with a semi-messy for loop. Maybe I should just do this? Maybe I am trying to simplify the code too much?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oops, misread the question:

```
var matchingOrders = from customer in customers
                     from order in customer.Orders
                     where order.ID == orderID
                     select order;

var order = matchingOrders.Single();
```

As in an earlier version of this answer, note that this will fail if there are no such matches or more than one. You may also want to look at `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, and `FirstOrDefault`.

This code can also be written without query expressions using `SelectMany`:

```
var order = customers.SelectMany(customer => customer.Orders)
                     .Single(order => order.ID == orderID);
```

Note that you *don't* need to use `Where` and then `Single` - there's a `Single` overload taking a predicate (and likewise for `FirstOrDefault` etc). Whether you use the query expression form or not is up to you - I *usually* use query expressions rather than `SelectMany`, but in this case you don't need the customer, so you can use the simple overload of `SelectMany`.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I want an Order item not a Customer. Bad enough you not reading my question properly, but 4 up-voters not reading it too? not a good day

Comment: good recovery ;) `SelectMany` is what I was looking for, didn't realise that existed. Gives me a concatenated collection to work with so I like that. Not a fan of query expressions myself - doesn't seem code-y enough for me

Comment: @musefan: For *short* queries, the extension method syntax is fine. When it comes to joins, groupings etc they can be really handy. It's worth being familiar with both styles.

Answer (score 2):

here 2 is Order id

```
    var selectedOrder = customers.SelectMany(cc => cc.Orders.Where(cc1 => cc1.ID == 2)).FirstOrDefault();
```